# NameError: name 'p' is not defined in

Tags: python

This code executes, however, an error message " NameError: name 'p' is not defined in lines 7 and 11 - I tried adding float(  ) around everything - same error - any ideas ????

```
def computepay(hrs,rate):

    if 0 < hrs <=40:
        print (hrs * rate)
    elif hrs > 40:
        print (40 * rate + (hrs-40)*rate*1.5)
    return p   <********  editor claims not defined here

    hrs = float(input("Enter Hours:"))
rate = float(input("Enter Rate per Hour:"))
p = computepay(hrs,rate)  <********  editor claims not defined here
print ("Pay", p)
```

Comment: well... `p` is *not* defined inside `def computepay(hrs,rate):`. you should assign some value to `p` before the `return` statement.

Comment: Yes, `p` variable is never defined before you call `computepay`  , you are simply printing the result , not storing it in `p` .

Comment: What type is `p`? Is it a string, an integer, a float, a complex number, a dictionary, a boolean, etc? How do you know? Where is it first created?

Comment: @PeterWood Type of `p` has nothing to do with this error.

Comment: @Alex.S The type of `p` is important for OP's understanding. The object which `p` is meant to point to is never created anywhere in the code. Asking OP to Identify its type is my way of helping OP think about why their code makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You try to return `p` in a function where p is not declared. I think you want to do this:

```
def computepay(hrs,rate):
    if 0 < hrs <=40:
        p = (hrs * rate)
    elif hrs > 40:
        p = (40 * rate + (hrs-40)*rate*1.5)
    print p
    return p
```

PS. The line `hrs = float(input("Enter Hours:"))` has a wrong indentation. Remove all white spaces before it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not defined in the function, is it?

There's no statement telling that:

```
p = ...
```

Perhaps you mean to assign p to "(40 * rate + (hrs-40)*rate*1.5)" if hrs > 40, and not only print it?

Answer (score 0):

If you read your script from top to bottom:

```
def computepay(hrs,rate):
```

The interpreter uses this to define a local function with name `computepay`. It then ignores everything in the block:

```
if 0 < hrs <=40:
    print (hrs * rate)
elif hrs > 40:
    print (40 * rate + (hrs-40)*rate*1.5)
return p
```

Then it executes `input`, converts the result into a *float* object using `float`, and creates a name `rate` which points to the *float* object:

```
rate = float(input("Enter Rate per Hour:"))
```

Then it executes `computepay` which does its thing and tries to return `p`, however, the intepreter has not yet seen any definition of `p` in the local scope. Even if we said `global p` to tell the interpreter to look in the global scope, it has not yet created the [**`NAME`**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) which points to any object. So you get a [**`NameError`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.NameError):

```
p = computepay(hrs,rate)
```

Comment: Your explanation is not really correct. You could write `p = 1` in the very first line but the error would be the same despite the fact that the interpreter has already obviously seen `p`. It has not seen `p` in a function where is's supposed to return `p`. That's the problem.

Comment: @Alex.S you are absolutely correct. Updated with local/global distinction.